# Change or reverse order of arguments

Tags: cursor-motions, rearrangement

A common task I run into is having to change the order of arguments. So, for example, I might have something like this:

```
stringInsert( "text to insert", buffer );
```

and need to change it into this:

```
stringInsert( buffer, "text to insert" );
```

Typically the way I do this is:

1. `da"` (or whatever is required to delete the first arg)
2. `f)h`  (or f, if I am inserting in the middle of the arg list)
3. `p`
4. Enter insert, insert any necessary spaces in insert mode, leave insert mode
5. Go back to beginning and delete unnecessary commas and spaces from beginning of arglist with `x`

Obviously, this is kind of tedious. What is a better way?

**UPDATE**

I have been trying out a macro that looks like this and so far it seems to be working pretty well:

```
da"2f_i,<ESC>p2F_x
```

Comment: Why can't you use a mapping if you want to use this multiple times and in different files?

Answer (score 6):

You can try to put this function in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! InvertArgs()
    " Get the arguments of the current line (remove the spaces)
    let args=substitute(matchstr(getline('.'), '(\zs.*\ze)'), '\s', '', 'g')

    " Split the arguments as a list and reverse the list
    let argsList=split(args, ',')
    call reverse(argsList)

    " Join the reversed list with a comma and a space separing the arguments
    let invertedArgs=join(argsList, ', ')

    " Remove the old arguments and put the new list
    execute "normal! 0f(ci(" . invertedArgs
endfunction
```

Go to the a line containing `function (arg1, arg2, arg3)` and call the function with

```
:call InvertArgs()
```

The main advantage of this function is that the number of arguments in your funciton doesn't matter.

You can also create a mapping like `nnoremap <key> :call InvertArgs()<CR>`

---

**Edit**: I just noticed that your example has a string with withe spaces in it: the function will mess with it, thus the subtitution in the first line should be removed like this:

```
let args=matchstr(getline('.'), '(\zs.*\ze)')
```

Answer (score 5):

Statox's is much more robust, but if you only wanted to ever do two arguments a lighter solution could be:

```
noremap <key> :s/(\(.*\), \(.*\))/(\2, \1)/e<CR>
```

This uses the search and replace function.

- `\(\)` captures output
- `\1` recalls the 1st capture
- `e` flag makes it not complain if the search fails

See `:h :s` for more info.

Comment: For two arguments your solution is way lighter than mine :-) I wonder if it would be possible to create patterns which would adapt to any number of arguments...

Comment: Maybe `submatch()` could be used? I have very little experience with it though. It's a function I've been meaning to look into for a while now but never have.

Comment: Same here: I know that I'm often impressed when I see people using `submatch()` cleverly but I've never trained myself enough to make it work properly. When I'll have time I'll check if I can find a way to do that!

Comment: I don't know how robust it is, but using the atom `\%#` to describe the current cursor position, maybe you could create a mapping which would adapt to any number of arguments: `nnoremap <key> :s/\v[(, ]+\zs(\k*%#\k+)(,\s*)(\k+)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-O>`

Answer (score 2):

[sideways.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim) is nice for this.  You can use `:SidewaysLeft` or `:SidewaysRight` to shift arguments and it's repeatable if you have [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) installed.

Text objects you could map:

```
omap aa <Plug>SidewaysArgumentTextobjA
xmap aa <Plug>SidewaysArgumentTextobjA
omap ia <Plug>SidewaysArgumentTextobjI
xmap ia <Plug>SidewaysArgumentTextobjI
```

Limitations I noticed:

- The text objects seem to be sensitive about where the cursor is placed.
- Selected text objects don't shrink or expand when repeated.